# How to set the setTimeout function every three seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to set the `setTimeout` function every three seconds so that it gets refreshed every three seconds without the need to reload the page.

How can I do this? This is what I've done so far.

**form**

```
<div class="messages msg_sent">
    <?php $timestamp1 = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
    <?php $mesgtimming = date(' D-h:i A', $timestamp1); ?>
    <p>
        <a
          href="#"
          data-toggle="tooltip"
          data-placement="right"
          title="<?php echo $mesgtimming; ?>"><?php echo $row->message; ?>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**script**

```
  success: function (data) {

    $('#chat_log').
      append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');

    $('#messages').val('');

  }
```

Comment: you can use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: how i am not getting @Atmahadli

Answer (score 0):

i will try to explain here.
since your code is not complete, so I can only guess :)

based on the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2)
your code should be:

```
setInterval(reloadChatLog, 3000);//1000==1sec

function reloadChatLog() {
  //...begin your ajax code here...
    success: function (data)
    {
      $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');

      $('#messagee').val('');
    },
  //...end your ajax code here...
}
```

Comment: your code is not working shall i put full script @Atmahadli

Comment: it is working if you can put that correctly. how you think that other people will understand your piece of code, if you can't understand my answer.

Comment: if your code is big code or it is secret, can you create a simple code that represent your real code.